# Slick carousel incorporation not working

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

I am trying to incorporate the slick carousel into my website but I am having a lot of trouble on what feels like the most basic of levels (I am a complete rookie with js). I am aiming to have 3 carousels stacked on top of each other each showing one image at a time.

Here is the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dpL2Y/1/embedded/result/

Below is my code:

Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<head>
<meta Charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Anderson.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>

</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="fmf.html">Fantastic Mr Fox</a></li>
        <li>The Life Aquatic</li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>The Grand Budapest Hotel</li>
        <li>Moonrise Kingdom</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="top">

<div><img src="imgs/lifehead.png"></div>
<div><img src="imgs/moonhead.png"></div>
<div><img src="imgs/foxhead.png"></div>
<div><img src="imgs/budahead.png"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="torso"></div>
<div id="legs"></div>

<footer></footer>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js">            <   /script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.top').slick({
            setting-name: setting-value
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: can u put this in www.jsfiddle.com ?

Comment: @OliverWatkins It's [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Slick Slider Working Example in Asp.net MVC and Asp.net Web Forms 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Slick-Slider

Answer (score 4):

`setting-name: setting-value` is just extra, you need to erase it.

It's only an example that the creator put. You should do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.top').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: Slick Slider Working Example in Asp.net MVC and Asp.net Web Forms 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Slick-Slider

Answer (score 1):

I know the thread is quite old, however I am struggling with slick as well.

First off in your html there are many errors (two closing body tags, a closing div tag where non belong,..)

Here's a clean and almost working jsfiddle of your code. The slick works (you can slide the divs using your mouse). However the Slick control elements don't seem to render (and this is where I'm always hanging).

http://jsfiddle.net/dpL2Y/8/

```
<body>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="fmf.html">Fantastic Mr Fox</a></li>
        <li>The Life Aquatic</li>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>The Grand Budapest Hotel</li>
        <li>Moonrise Kingdom</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="top">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <div>Item 4</div>
</div>
</body>
```

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.top').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1
});
});
```

I added the the css, jquery and slick files using external resources (left hand side).

Assuming you already gave up or fixed the issue, maybe this helps others to get their slick working.

Comment: Slick Slider Working Example in Asp.net MVC and Asp.net Web Forms 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Slick-Slider

Answer (score 0):

The example you've shown is locally referencing css and js that aren't available. In order for this to work properly, you need to put the /slick folder in your root directory. A good way to troubleshoot this would be to open your developer console to make sure the required resources are loading.

Comment: Slick Slider Working Example in Asp.net MVC and Asp.net Web Forms 
https://code2night.com/Blog/MyBlog/Slick-Slider

Answer (score 0):

You need to add http: in front of the //code.jquery.com...
    (`http://code.jquery.com...`)

Comment: No. Putting `//` at the beginning of the URL will use either HTTP or HTTPS, depending on the protocol of the current page.